# One-column table not properly displayed by TableForm

Tags: formatting, list-manipulation

I want a table with a single column of data, and with headings along both the rows and the column. One might expect it to work like this:

```
TableForm[{"one", "two", "three"}, 
 TableHeadings -> {{"$10MM", "$20MM", "$30MM"}, {"col"}}]
```

But this does not work; it displays the data and the row labels correctly, but it does not label the column. What am I missing?

Comment: Your data consists of a single row... try `TableForm[List /@ {"one", "two", "three"}, 
 TableHeadings -> {{"$10MM", "$20MM", "$30MM"}, {"col"}}]`...

Comment: `TableForm[List /@ {"one", "two", "three"}, 
 TableHeadings -> {{"$10MM", "$20MM", "$30MM"}, {"col"}}]`

Comment: @belisarius huh?

Comment: or {{"one"},{"two"},{"three"}} ..

Comment: @YvesKlett I should've micro-slept. Didn't see your comment. Well, now you know _for sure_ it was the  right thing to write :D

Comment: @belisarius and *you even got the upvote earlier*! Man, I really seem to be a people person :D

Comment: @YvesKlett [Me too!](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wr1dc.png)

Comment: TableForm[Transpose[{{"one", "two", "three"}}], 
 TableHeadings -> {{"$10MM", "$20MM", "$30MM"}, {"col"}}]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You present a single row vector to `TableForm`, which is rather hankering for a column vector (or matrix).

Instead of `{"one", "two", "three"}` you need `{{"one"}, {"two"}, {"three"}}`. There are many ways to achieve this, one of them `List /@ {"one", "two", "three"}`:

```
TableForm[List /@ {"one", "two", "three"}, 
 TableHeadings -> {{"$10MM", "$20MM", "$30MM"}, {"col"}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer:

```
Grid[{{"", "col"}}~Join~
  Transpose[{{"$10M", "$20M", "$30M"}, {"one", "two", "three"}}], 
 Dividers -> All]
```

because of its clarity and all the additional Grid-options.

Answer (score 1):

To be different, and to illustrate behavior of `TableForm` which I previously described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5011242/618728), which is that directions flip with every additional `List` level:

```
TableForm[
 {{{"one", "two", "three"}}}, 
 TableHeadings -> {{Column@{"$10MM", "$20MM", "$30MM"}}, {"col"}}
]
```

There may be a cleaner way to do the headings than using `Column` but I can't think of it at the moment.