# Arrange Grid of Table elements horizontally

Tags: list-manipulation, grid-layouts

I have a Table consisting of an independent variable and two functions. I want to output it like this:

```
x   1    2    3    4    5  ...
f f(1) f(2) f(3) f(4) f(5) ...
g g(1) g(2) g(3) g(4) g(5) ...
```

but doing

```
Grid[Table[...]]
```

arranges the values vertically. Any way around this?

Comment: Look up [`Transpose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html)

Comment: See also `TableDirections` option of `TableForm`.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [(46483)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46483/121),
[(48821)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/48821/121).  Also see:  [(5011242)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5011242/618728)

Answer (score 2):

This is a canonical way of getting what you want:

```
data = Table[i[j], {i, {f, g}}, {j, 1, 5}];
TraditionalForm@TableForm[
  data,
  TableHeadings -> {{f, g}, Range[5]}]
```

\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
 \text{} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
 \hline
 f & f(1) & f(2) & f(3) & f(4) & f(5) \\
 g & g(1) & g(2) & g(3) & g(4) & g(5) \\
\end{array}

Sorry I can't easily get the "x" in the top. If that's important, the other answer is better.

Answer (score 0):

Although there are probably slightly more elegant answers, the following works:

```
gridDraw[N_] := 
  Module[{aRange = Range[N], bRange = Range[N], cRange}, PrependTo[bRange, ""]; 
Grid[{bRange, Flatten[{f, f /@ aRange}], Flatten[{g, g /@ aRange}]},
Frame -> All]]
```

By just calling:

```
gridDraw[5]
```

You get exactly the same as above (apart from the square parentheses):

\begin{array}{cccccc}
 \text{} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
 f & f(1) & f(2) & f(3) & f(4) & f(5) \\
 g & g(1) & g(2) & g(3) & g(4) & g(5) \\
\end{array}

Hope that helps.